# Getting the selected option as text/string ffrom a drop-down in Selenium?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where I need to get the current selection from the drop down as a text or String and compare it for further assertion, but when I try the getText(), I get the complete list of items in the drop down, how can I get the currently selected item from drop down.

```
<form id="MODIFY_ATTRIBUTES" class="formList" method="post" action="jfn?ctxcontractId=L4%3A2274&mfunc=30&ctxnavCtx=C&cfunc=228&ctxaccountId=L4%3A1877&oid=L4%3A2042&ctx=L&octx=110&jfnRC=1">
<hr/>
<div class="formListTab">
<fieldset>
<div>
<label class="mandatory" for="p-param-L4:80000">Language</label>
<select id="p-param-L4:80000" name="p-param-L4:80000">
<option value="p-param-L4:80000-L4:12610">English</option>
<option selected="selected" value="p-param-L4:80000-L4:12600">French (Standard)</option>
<option value="p-param-L4:80000-L4:12830">Dutch</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I used the below XPATH, but it returns the complete list of items from the drop-down.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='MODIFY_ATTRIBUTES']/fieldset[1]/div/select")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the text of whole Select element instead of just the selected option. You may use the inbuilt function to fetch selected option then fetch the text from this. Use Following:

```
String selectedOption = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("p-param-L4:80000"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

However if you want to use xpath. You may try following:

```
String selectedOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='p-param-L4:80000']/option[@selected='selected']")).getText();
```

I would recommend Id to fetch your required text.